# Repetitive Time Series analysis

Tags: r, time-series, repeated-measures

I'm a student and I'm trying to make a brief analysis of flight tickets prices.

I've got for some days flight prices on a specific route for the day and for 90 days ahead. I've done this twice per day. I'd like to estimate the weekday effect (i think prices would rise during the weekend) on price but I don't know how to handle repetitive measures. Any advice?

Thank you.

A portion of data:

```
data=structure(list(Date = structure(c(rep(17569,238),rep(17570,236),rep(17571,234),rep(1572,232)
                              ), class = "Date"), Time = c(rep("10:00",119),rep("16:00",119),
                                                           rep("10:00",118),rep("16:00",118),
                                                           rep("10:00",117),rep("16:00",117),
                                                           rep("10:00",116),rep("16:00",116)), 
                                                  Price = c(152.89, 128.69, 181.49, 128.69, 128.69, 128.69, 152.89, 128.69, 89.09, 
                                                             106.69, 106.69, 128.69, 74.79, 62.69, 52.79, 62.69, 74.79, 74.79, 
                                                             62.69, 52.79, 74.79, 74.79, 62.69, 74.79, 52.79, 74.79, 62.69, 
                                                             62.69, 47.51, 47.51, 43.99, 62.69, 62.69, 62.69, 39.59, 39.59, 
                                                             47.51, 52.79, 43.99, 52.79, 47.51, 39.59, 32.66, 32.66, 52.79, 
                                                             43.99, 43.99, 52.79, 52.79, 62.69, 74.79, 74.79, 74.79, 43.99, 
                                                                                 106.69, 181.49, 152.89, 106.69, 89.09, 89.09, 106.69, 89.09, 
                                                                                 74.79, 62.69, 39.59, 52.79, 62.69, 62.69, 62.69, 74.79, 74.79, 
                                                                                 62.69, 43.99, 52.79, 43.99, 39.59, 62.69, 74.79, 62.69, 74.79, 
                                                                                 106.69, 74.79, 89.09, 128.69, 74.79, 74.79, 62.69, 62.69, 62.69, 
                                                                                 52.79, 43.99, 52.79, 62.69, 62.69, 74.79, 62.69, 52.79, 52.79, 
                                                                                 43.99, 52.79, 62.69, 52.79, 62.69, 52.79, 43.99, 43.99, 43.99, 
                                                                                 52.79, 52.79, 52.79, 52.79, 36.29, 52.79, 52.79, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                                 NA, NA, 0, 128.69, 152.89, 106.69, 106.69, 89.09, 128.69, 106.69, 
                                                                                 74.79, 89.09, 106.69, 128.69, 74.79, 62.69, 52.79, 62.69, 74.79, 
                                                                                 74.79, 74.79, 52.79, 74.79, 74.79, 62.69, 89.09, 52.79, 74.79, 
                                                                                 62.69, 62.69, 47.51, 47.51, 32.66, 52.79, 62.69, 62.69, 32.66, 
                                                                                 32.66, 39.59, 43.99, 43.99, 52.79, 62.69, 39.59, 32.66, 32.66, 
                                                                                 52.79, 43.99, 43.99, 52.79, 52.79, 62.69, 74.79, 74.79, 74.79, 
                                                                                 43.99, 106.69, 181.49, 152.89, 106.69, 89.09, 89.09, 106.69, 
                                                                                 89.09, 74.79, 47.51, 32.66, 43.99, 52.79, 62.69, 39.59, 47.51, 
                                                                                 47.51, 47.51, 32.66, 43.99, 32.66, 32.66, 47.51, 62.69, 47.51, 
                                                                                 62.69, 106.69, 74.79, 74.79, 106.69, 62.69, 62.69, 52.79, 52.79, 
                                                                                 52.79, 36.29, 36.29, 43.99, 52.79, 52.79, 62.69, 52.79, 43.99, 
                                                                                 43.99, 26.72, 43.99, 52.79, 43.99, 43.99, 43.99, 32.66, 32.66, 
                                                                                 32.66, 43.99, 43.99, 43.99, 43.99, 29.69, 43.99, 36.29, NA, NA, 
                                                                                 NA, NA, NA, 152.89, 215.59, 128.69, 128.69, 152.89, 152.89, 181.49, 
                                                                                 106.69, 106.69, 106.69, 128.69, 89.09, 62.69, 62.69, 74.79, 74.79, 
                                                                                 74.79, 89.09, 47.51, 74.79, 62.69, 74.79, 89.09, 62.69, 74.79, 
                                                                                 74.79, 47.51, 47.51, 39.59, 52.79, 52.79, 62.69, 56.42, 39.59, 
                                                                                 39.59, 47.51, 62.69, 39.59, 62.69, 56.42, 39.59, 32.66, 39.59, 
                                                                                 52.79, 43.99, 43.99, 62.69, 52.79, 62.69, 74.79, 74.79, 74.79, 
                                                                                 43.99, 106.69, 181.49, 152.89, 106.69, 89.09, 89.09, 106.69, 
                                                                                 74.79, 74.79, 62.69, 39.59, 52.79, 62.69, 62.69, 47.51, 62.69, 
                                                                                 62.69, 47.51, 52.79, 52.79, 43.99, 39.59, 62.69, 74.79, 74.79, 
                                                                                 74.79, 106.69, 74.79, 89.09, 128.69, 74.79, 74.79, 62.69, 62.69, 
                                                                                 62.69, 52.79, 43.99, 43.99, 62.69, 62.69, 74.79, 62.69, 52.79, 
                                                                                 52.79, 43.99, 52.79, 62.69, 52.79, 62.69, 52.79, 43.99, 43.99, 
                                                                                 43.99, 52.79, 52.79, 52.79, 52.79, 36.29, 52.79, 52.79, NA, NA, 
                                                                                 NA, NA, NA, 0, 215.59, 106.69, 106.69, 128.69, 128.69, 215.59, 
                                                                                 106.69, 106.69, 106.69, 152.89, 106.69, 62.69, 74.79, 74.79, 
                                                                                 74.79, 74.79, 89.09, 47.51, 74.79, 74.79, 74.79, 89.09, 62.69, 
                                                                                 89.09, 74.79, 47.51, 47.51, 47.51, 52.79, 52.79, 62.69, 56.42, 
                                                                                 39.59, 39.59, 47.51, 62.69, 39.59, 62.69, 56.42, 39.59, 39.59, 
                                                                                 39.59, 52.79, 52.79, 43.99, 62.69, 52.79, 62.69, 74.79, 74.79, 
                                                                                 74.79, 43.99, 106.69, 181.49, 152.89, 106.69, 89.09, 89.09, 106.69, 
                                                                                 74.79, 74.79, 62.69, 39.59, 52.79, 62.69, 62.69, 47.51, 62.69, 
                                                                                 62.69, 47.51, 52.79, 52.79, 43.99, 39.59, 62.69, 74.79, 74.79, 
                                                                                 74.79, 106.69, 74.79, 89.09, 128.69, 74.79, 74.79, 62.69, 62.69, 
                                                                                 62.69, 52.79, 43.99, 43.99, 62.69, 62.69, 74.79, 62.69, 52.79, 
                                                                                 52.79, 43.99, 52.79, 62.69, 52.79, 62.69, 52.79, 43.99, 43.99, 
                                                                                 43.99, 52.79, 52.79, 52.79, 52.79, 36.29, 52.79, 52.79, NA, NA, 
                                                                                 NA, NA, NA, 0, 128.69, 152.89, 152.89, 215.59, 181.49, 106.69, 
                                                                                 106.69, 106.69, 152.89, 106.69, 74.79, 74.79, 74.79, 74.79, 74.79, 
                                                                                 89.09, 47.51, 74.79, 74.79, 67.31, 106.69, 47.51, 89.09, 67.31, 
                                                                                 56.42, 47.51, 47.51, 47.51, 47.51, 62.69, 56.42, 39.59, 39.59, 
                                                                                 47.51, 62.69, 39.59, 47.51, 56.42, 39.59, 32.66, 39.59, 52.79, 
                                                                                 43.99, 43.99, 62.69, 43.99, 62.69, 74.79, 74.79, 62.69, 43.99, 
                                                                                 106.69, 181.49, 152.89, 106.69, 89.09, 106.69, 106.69, 74.79, 
                                                                                 74.79, 56.42, 39.59, 52.79, 62.69, 52.79, 47.51, 56.42, 56.42, 
                                                                                 47.51, 39.59, 52.79, 39.59, 39.59, 56.42, 74.79, 74.79, 74.79, 
                                                                                 106.69, 74.79, 89.09, 128.69, 74.79, 74.79, 62.69, 62.69, 62.69, 
                                                                                 52.79, 43.99, 52.79, 52.79, 62.69, 74.79, 62.69, 52.79, 52.79, 
                                                                                 39.59, 52.79, 62.69, 52.79, 62.69, 52.79, 52.79, 39.59, 39.59, 
                                                                                 52.79, 52.79, 52.79, 52.79, 36.29, 43.99, 52.79, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                                 NA, NA, 0, 106.69, 128.69, 128.69, 215.59, 181.49, 106.69, 106.69, 
                                                                                 106.69, 152.89, 106.69, 74.79, 74.79, 74.79, 74.79, 74.79, 89.09, 
                                                                                 47.51, 74.79, 74.79, 67.31, 106.69, 62.69, 89.09, 67.31, 56.42, 
                                                                                 47.51, 47.51, 62.69, 62.69, 62.69, 56.42, 39.59, 39.59, 47.51, 
                                                                                 62.69, 39.59, 47.51, 56.42, 39.59, 32.66, 39.59, 52.79, 43.99, 
                                                                                 43.99, 74.79, 43.99, 62.69, 74.79, 74.79, 74.79, 43.99, 106.69, 
                                                                                 181.49, 152.89, 106.69, 89.09, 106.69, 106.69, 89.09, 74.79, 
                                                                                 62.69, 39.59, 52.79, 62.69, 52.79, 47.51, 62.69, 62.69, 47.51, 
                                                                                 43.99, 52.79, 43.99, 39.59, 62.69, 74.79, 74.79, 74.79, 106.69, 
                                                                                 74.79, 89.09, 128.69, 74.79, 74.79, 62.69, 62.69, 62.69, 52.79, 
                                                                                 43.99, 52.79, 52.79, 62.69, 74.79, 62.69, 52.79, 52.79, 43.99, 
                                                                                 52.79, 62.69, 52.79, 62.69, 52.79, 52.79, 43.99, 43.99, 52.79, 
                                                                                 52.79, 52.79, 52.79, 43.99, 43.99, 52.79, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                                 181.49, 152.89, 181.49, 181.49, 181.49, 106.69, 106.69, 106.69, 
                                                                                 128.69, 106.69, 74.79, 74.79, 74.79, 74.79, 74.79, 89.09, 56.42, 
                                                                                 74.79, 56.42, 67.31, 89.09, 62.69, 74.79, 89.09, 56.42, 47.51, 
                                                                                 47.51, 62.69, 47.51, 74.79, 56.42, 39.59, 39.59, 47.51, 47.51, 
                                                                                 39.59, 62.69, 56.42, 39.59, 32.66, 39.59, 52.79, 43.99, 43.99, 
                                                                                 74.79, 43.99, 52.79, 74.79, 74.79, 74.79, 43.99, 128.69, 181.49, 
                                                                                 152.89, 106.69, 89.09, 106.69, 106.69, 89.09, 74.79, 47.51, 39.59, 
                                                                                 52.79, 62.69, 52.79, 47.51, 62.69, 62.69, 47.51, 43.99, 52.79, 
                                                                                 43.99, 39.59, 62.69, 74.79, 62.69, 74.79, 106.69, 74.79, 89.09, 
                                                                                 128.69, 74.79, 74.79, 62.69, 62.69, 62.69, 52.79, 43.99, 52.79, 
                                                                                 52.79, 52.79, 74.79, 62.69, 52.79, 52.79, 43.99, 52.79, 62.69, 
                                                                                 52.79, 62.69, 43.99, 52.79, 43.99, 43.99, 52.79, 52.79, 52.79, 
                                                                                 52.79, 43.99, 43.99, 52.79, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 152.89, 181.49, 
                                                                                 181.49, 181.49, 128.69, 106.69, 106.69, 128.69, 128.69, 74.79, 
                                                                                 74.79, 89.09, 74.79, 74.79, 89.09, 56.42, 74.79, 74.79, 67.31, 
                                                                                 89.09, 62.69, 74.79, 89.09, 56.42, 47.51, 47.51, 62.69, 47.51, 
                                                                                 74.79, 56.42, 39.59, 39.59, 47.51, 47.51, 39.59, 62.69, 56.42, 
                                                                                 39.59, 39.59, 39.59, 52.79, 43.99, 43.99, 74.79, 52.79, 52.79, 
                                                                                 74.79, 74.79, 74.79, 43.99, 128.69, 181.49, 152.89, 106.69, 89.09, 
                                                                                 106.69, 106.69, 89.09, 74.79, 47.51, 39.59, 52.79, 62.69, 52.79, 
                                                                                 47.51, 62.69, 62.69, 47.51, 43.99, 52.79, 43.99, 39.59, 62.69, 
                                                                                 74.79, 62.69, 74.79, 106.69, 74.79, 89.09, 128.69, 74.79, 74.79, 
                                                                                 62.69, 62.69, 62.69, 52.79, 43.99, 52.79, 52.79, 52.79, 74.79, 
                                                                                 62.69, 52.79, 52.79, 43.99, 52.79, 62.69, 52.79, 62.69, 52.79, 
                                                                                 52.79, 43.99, 43.99, 52.79, 52.79, 52.79, 52.79, 43.99, 43.99, 
                                                                                 52.79, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), flight_date = structure(c(seq(17569,17687), seq(17569,17687), seq(17570,17687), seq(17570,17687),
                                                                                                                                       seq(17571,17687), seq(17571,17687), seq(17572,17687), seq(17572,17687))
                                                                                                                                       , class = "Date")), .Names = c("Date", "Time", 
                                                                                                                                       "Price", "flight_date"), row.names = c(1:940), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to include dummy variables for every day of the week. In that way you account for the day of the week.

You add a column for each day of the week. So 6 columns (if you are only interested in week or weekend then 1 columns). And you put 1 or 0 in if it's the that day or not. 
Don't forget, that when you do linear regression with dummies, you only have include k-1 dummies! (dummy variable trap if you want to look it up)
Therefore 6 columns for every day of the week, and 1 for weekend or not weekend.

Example: when you have week versus weekend you would include the variable weekend in your regression where observations occurring on a weekend day have a 1. But you would not add an extra week variable in the regression. Weekday would be your base group. When interpreting your coefficient you would say: on weekends the prices increases by xx (here insert beta estimator) compared to week days.

Same interpretation if you would include all days of the week!

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thank you! I think it can be a solution, I'll try! Actually I'm looking for the best way to approach the problem. For example: I thought to estimate an ARIMA model for each series with a seasonality of 7 and then to compute the mean of the seasonalities estimated. But I don't know if it is a good idea since I have little experience with time series.